# Custom sonarqube plugin - proxy service

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've a requirement to develop a `custom sonarqube plugin` that will act as a proxy service.

I'm thinking of creating a simple Java application which:

- Application will keep on listening for request
- Receives a REST api URL (some 3rd party address) from caller as request
- Hits REST api and receives JSON response back
- Forward the response back to original caller

My question is, is it possible within sonarqube?

Supposing, it is possible:
Second question - I’ve gone thru [sonarqube documentation](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/6.7/apidocs/overview-summary.html), but I’m not able to pinpoint which plugin class to use. Should I use PageDefinition only?

Please suggest.
*Thanks*

*P.S. - Similar question was posted on [sonarqube community](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/custom-plugin-only-for-proxy-purpose/1341), posting it here for broader audience.*

Answer (score 2):

> I'm thinking of creating a simple Java application which:
>
> - Application will keep on listening for request
> - Receives a REST api URL (some 3rd party address) from caller as request
> - Hits REST api and receives JSON response back
> - Forward the response back to original caller
>
> My question is, is it possible within sonarqube?

It is possible to add third party library into a Custom SonarQube Plugin. You can create tasks in which you can do whatever you implement.

> Supposing, it is possible: Second question - I’ve gone thru sonarqube
>   documentation, but I’m not able to pinpoint which plugin class to use.
>   Should I use PageDefinition only?

You should implement [WebService Extension Point](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/master/sonar-plugin-api/src/main/java/org/sonar/api/server/ws/WebService.java) which allow you to extend SonarQube web API and add new bahaviours on requests.

PageDefinition is a way to add some web pages on the WebUI.